# Decoding html entities from database

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, doctrine

I'm having some problems displaying strings with html entity on the web browser.

Currently i'm working on one system where string (e.g. file name) containing some html spec chars like single quotes could be stored to database encoded as html entity.

When i fetch that record from database and want to display that "file name" on page it shows me the same text.

**For example:**

```
filename in database: exampleFileName&#39;

i want to display on page: exampleFileName'
```

I know that there is php functions such as html_entity_decode() and etc.

But i think it would be stupid to use it everywhere where i'm passing this string to html view.

Application is created using Zend Framework 2 and it's using Doctrine2 ORM.

Does doctrine can't handle this ? I mean is it possible somehow to get that string from database already decoded as normal text?

Or maybe it's something wrong with database default collation (utf8_swedish_ci)?

Finally, 
what are the best practices for storing such kind of strings (with single quotes) into database ?

I would be really grateful for some answers.

Thank you.

Comment: damn, you should not store your data in their equivalents HTML entities in the first place

Comment: Yes, HTML entities are for HTML, not for databases.